# WSO2 Installation error

Tags: wso2

Hoping you can help, I've installed WS02 EMM product on our server.
I've followed the instruction on setting the SMTP setting etc...

I've gone to start the service and I get the following error.

```
 C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\wso2emm-2.0.1\wso2emm-2.0.1\bin
    C:\wso2emm-2.0.1\wso2emm-2.0.1\bin>wso2server.bat
    JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92
    CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\WSO2EM~1.1\WSO2EM~1.1\bin\..
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m;        sup
    port was removed in 8.0
    [2016-09-08 13:16:20,446]  INFO         {org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.impl.internal.AppDiscove
   ryComponent} -  WebApp Discovery component activated
   [2016-09-08 13:16:20,477]  INFO    {org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.mobile.internal.AppManag
erMobileComponent} -  WSO2MDM_INTERNAL MDM is bound to App Manager
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,493]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.mobile.internal.AppManag
erMobileComponent} -  App Manger Mobile Component activated
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,680]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivat
or} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,696]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivat
or} -  Operating System : Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3, amd64
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,696]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivat
or} -  Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,696]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivat
or} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_92
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,696]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivat
or} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.92-b14,Oracle Cor
poration
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,696]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivat
or} -  Carbon Home      : C:\WSO2EM~1.1\WSO2EM~1.1\bin\..
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,696]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivat
or} -  Java Temp Dir    : C:\WSO2EM~1.1\WSO2EM~1.1\bin\..\tmp
[2016-09-08 13:16:20,696]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivat
or} -  User             : adm-hre-rdodd, en-GB, Europe/London
[2016-09-08 13:16:21,415]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.Vali
dationResultPrinter} -  The running OS : Windows Server 2012 R2 is not a tested
Operating System for running WSO2 Carbon
[2016-09-08 13:16:21,415]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.Vali
dationResultPrinter} -  Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2ca
rbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, conf
igure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
Activating org.wso2.jaggery.scxml with RealmService enabled
[2016-09-08 13:16:31,140]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegi
stryService} -  Configured Registry in 234ms
[2016-09-08 13:16:31,265]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.Registry
CoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2016-09-08 13:16:34,312]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  T
LD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2016-09-08 13:16:50,328]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClie
nt} -  Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2016-09-08 13:16:50,962]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.social.sql.SocialDBInitilizer}
-  Social database already exists. Not creating a new database.
[2016-09-08 13:16:51,071]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgt
DSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2016-09-08 13:16:52,477] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
-  WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.Utils.replaceSystemProperty(Utils.java:100)

        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(Carbon
ServerManager.java:354)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(Carbo
nServerManager.java:290)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(Pr
eAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEv
ent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventM
anager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(Even
tManager.java:340)
```

Has anyone seen this issue before?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ryan

Comment: What is the EMM version? And do you see the same error in a fresh pack without any config changes?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. Version we have is 2.0.1. No we did not see the issue with fresh config. Just since I have edited the XML Files.

Comment: what is the change in xml file? could you post that?