# Error when starting WSO2 EMM server "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

When I try and run `wso2server.bat`, I get this error (running on Server 2012 R2):

> C:\Users\beeez\Documents\wso2emm-2.2.0\bin>wso2server.bat
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
>   CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Users\beeez\DOCUME~1\WSO2EM~1.0\
>   bin..
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; sup
>   port was removed in 8.0
>   **Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap**

I do not have `CARBON_HOME` manually set. I can run WSO2 Carbon server perfectly fine with the `wso2server.bat` located in the extracted files for carbon. Doesn't make sense why one piece of software will start but the other won't.

I can run the EMM server on my personal computer perfectly fine but it doesn't want to run on the dedicated Windows Server install.

Comment: For some reason, your `CARBON_HOME` is wrong.  Having `WSO2EM~1.0`, (instead of 2.2.0) in the path must give you some clue. Try to echo `CARBON_HOME` and see what you get.

Comment: How would CARBON_HOME be wrong if I don't have it set? It is automatically being set.

echo CARBON_HOME
CARBON_HOME

Comment: Yeah, it **should** work if you didn't set it manually. But as I said, somehow, a wrong path is set. (do you have a path with `WSO2EM~1.0`?) And in windows, the command should be `echo %CARBON_HOME%`, I think.

Comment: @Bhathiya  Sorry forgot I needed percents around the variable. just returns %CARBON_HOME% back to me. 

I do not have a path with that at all. Like I mentioned, this seems to only be an issue with starting the EMM software. 

I can download, extract, and run wso2server.bat from this software by them (http://wso2.com/products/carbon/) perfectly fine. CARBON_HOME sets itself and I can get to the web address for it. It's only a problem with EMM.

Comment: Hmm.. that's strange. Did you try setting CARBON_HOME explicitly? Does that work?

Comment: I found this which has a similar `carbon_home` path. Looks like a windows thing and I have no idea about that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394211/wso2-installation-error

Answer (score 0):

This is just a random idea.

In `wso2server.bat`, replace this line

```
if "%CARBON_HOME%"=="" set CARBON_HOME=%~sdp0..
```

with

```
set CARBON_HOME=%~sdp0..
```

Comment: I rebuilt the VM and started from cratch with jdk 1.8 and extracted the files again but still getting the same thing. Made your change too.

`C:\Program Files\wso2emm-2.2.0\bin>wso2server.bat
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2EM~1.0\bin\..
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap`

Comment: I also tried setting CARBON_HOME to the install location but still no luck.


`C:\Program Files\wso2emm-2.2.0\bin>wso2server.bat
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\wso2emm-2.2.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap`

Comment: Better to avoid spaces in the path.  Can you try 
again?

Comment: Moved the files to C:. `CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\wso2emm-2.2.0` also tried it with your change in this answer: `CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\WSO2EM~1.0\bin\..` still getting the same error on both: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap`

Comment: Did you try hardcoding the path in as `set CARBON_HOME=/path/to/home`

Comment: Yes in my second reply. If you mean path to home as in the directory where the EMM folders are. `CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\wso2emm-2.2.0`

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea what's going on. I don't have a way to test myself either since I don't have windows with me.